# Pandas dataframe to dictionary with ID as Key

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my pandas dataframe, Now I want to create the dictionary out of this so that a dictionary of records, where the keys are record_ids and the values are dictionaries with the keys being field names, Something Like this:

I have used df.to_dict() function but not sure how to make record_ids as key using this.

```
{123342: {'Address': 'Brunswick',
  'Id': '123342',
  'Name': 'Rachels Hunt',
  'Unname': 'VB INDUSTRIES',
  'no': '6032',
  'zip': '01123'}}
```

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let use `set_index` and `to_dict()`:

```
df.set_index(df.Id).T.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{123342: {'Address': 'Brunswick',
  'Id': 123342,
  'Name': 'Rachels Hunt',
  'Unname': 'VB INDUSTRIES',
  'no': 6032,
  'zip': 1123}}
```

***Note:*** I am not moving the Id column into the index, but I am creating a new index identical to the Id column.

Where

```
print(df)

       Id    Address          Name         Unname    no   zip
0  123342  Brunswick  Rachels Hunt  VB INDUSTRIES  6032  1123
```

### Edit for comment below:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str)).set_index(df.Id).T.to_dict()
```

output:

```
{123342: {'Address': 'Brunswick',
  'Id': '123342',
  'Name': 'Rachels Hunt',
  'Unname': 'VB INDUSTRIES',
  'no': '6032',
  'zip': '1123'}}
```

Comment: But it's changing the data type of the numerics from String to Integer, check Id and no fields.

Comment: Yeah, that is beause I created the dataframe with int datatypes.  if i convert those ints to strings it yeilds strings.

Answer (score 1):

Dict to dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(d).T
Out[836]: 
              Address      Id          Name         Unname    no    zip
123342  Brunswick  123342  Rachels Hunt  VB INDUSTRIES  6032  01123
```

Dataframe to Dict

EDIT :

```
df.T.to_dict()
Out[850]: 
{123342: {'Address': 'Brunswick',
  'Id': '123342',
  'Name': 'Rachels Hunt',
  'Unname': 'VB INDUSTRIES',
  'no': '6032',
  'zip': '01123'}}
```

Comment: The ID key inside the nested dictionary is missing

Comment: this doesnt give the result, df.set_index('Id').T.to_dict() , still Id missing,

Comment: `df.T.to_dict()` it will @min2bro

Comment: @min2bro what is your input ? could you add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = [
    {
        d['Id']: {
            'Address'   : d['Address'],
            'Id'        : d['Id'],
            'Name'      : d['Name'],
            'Unname'    : d['Unname'],
            'no'        : d['no'],
            'zip'       : d['zip']
        }
    } 
    for d in df.to_dict(orient = 'records')
]
```